# how to append a number to a function name to create many functions?

Tags: javascript

i ve a function which is responsible for some validations, disabling and enabling of some text boxes and a group of radio buttons ....

now i want to generate the function name to be called from another function using a for loop and then appending the for loop index to the function in question ....

something like this .....

```
function unCheckRadio(num) 
{
  var cont = num;
  var form = document.angular;

  for (var i = 0; i < cont; i++) 
  {
     alert(form['lim_set'+i].length);
     for(var j = 0; j < form['lim_set'+i].length; j++ )
     {
       form['lim_set'+i][j].checked = form['lim_set'+i][j].defaultChecked;
     }
     makeChoice_ang();
  }

}
```

here i want to append the index i to the makeChoice_ang() function ....

tried many ways .... but no go ...

i tried using this .... 'makeChoice_ang'+i;

but this is making it an string ....

Please help me out or atleast point me in the right direction ....

Thanks a million in advance !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*I'm adding this as a different answer because, well, it's different!*

If you want to call a global function (or any function you know the scope of) given a suffix like that, then you could just use array notation:

```
window['makeChoice_ang' + i]();
```

Remember... eval is evil [mostly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil)

Comment: Thanks a heap nick .... worked like a charm ... thanks to all others too ... i couldn't use arrays thats why i was in this fix ... i should have mentioned that ... 

Thanks a ton to stack overflow

Answer (score 3):

It seems like it would be easier to re-do `makeChoice_ang()` as a generic function that accepts an index as a parameter.  Alternatively, if you can't change the function or if the behavior will vary wildly from function to function you could just use `eval()` to evaluate your string.

Answer (score 2):

Make an object to put your functions into. Make a method in this object for each 'makeChoice_ang'+i function. You can then call these functions through that object.

```
var f = {
   makeChoice_ang1: function(){
      alert('1');
   },
   makeChoice_ang2: function(){
      alert('2');
   }
}

for(var i = 1; i < 3;i++)
   f['makeChoice_ang' + i]();
```

Comment: an array would probably be easier

Comment: yeah I realized that after I read the other answers. The advantage here though (if its even an advantage), is you have names for the functions.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you're trying to do:

```
eval('makeChoice_ang'+i+'()');
```

This will call the function created by that string concatenation. If `i = 5`, then it would call `makeChoice_ang5()`.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, functions are treated as normal variables, just like a string or an int. obviously they have some extra features, but you can use them in the same way, for example, you could store a number of functions in an array, or pass a function to another function. Given that, I can't see any need to name functions in the way it looks like you're trying to.

I wish I could give you some more help for your specific problem, but it's a little hard to understand, sorry.

You could try changing your `unCheckRadio` function so that it takes a function as a parameter:

```
function unCheckRadio(num, func) { ... }
```

and then you'd call it like this:

```
function unCheckRadio(5, function() {
    // do whatever here.
});
```